# Is this riddle too obvious?

Tags: riddle

> My friends hate me,
>
> my enemies love me,
>
> my leader puts a leash around my neck,
>
> my enemies reward me and beg.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are :

> a traitor !

My friends hate me, my enemies love me,

> it is obvious

my leader puts a leash around my neck,

> Your leader will punish the traitor

my enemies reward me and beg.

> Enemies will beg and reward you for informations you have.

Comment: Oh my! I think you misused the spoilers!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir : Oh.... sorry.... thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is based on Jamal's answer

> It could be informer/informant

Who

> is liked by enemies and hated by friends and is often rewarded by enemies. Leash around the neck could be 'bounty' on suspects (of informers/spies).